# Query Dsl get grouped objects

Tags: java, querydsl

I have these classes/entities:

```
class Item {
  int id;
  String name;
}

class Sale {
 Item item;
 double value;
}
```

How to get sums of sales groupped by Items using Query DSL?

I can run this query:

```
QSale sale = QSale.sale;
QItem item = QItem.item;

from(sale).join(sale.item, item).groupBy(item).list(item.id, sale.value.sum())
```

But this returns only item ids and their sums, but how to get whole Item objects and their sums?

If I write query as:

```
from(sale).join(sale.item, item).groupBy(item).list(item, sale.value.sum())
```

I will get:

> Column 'Item.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
QSale sale = QSale.sale;
QItem item = QItem.item;

query.from(sale)
  .join(sale.item, item)
  .list(item.id, sale.value.sum())
  .transform(GroupBy.groupBy(item).as(GroupBy.sum(sale.value)))
```

`GroupBy` starts where `groupBy` ends. It provides deep aggregation functionality via result post processing http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.6.2/reference/html/ch03s02.html#d0e2185

Comment: The important part of the function is ".. aggregate query results in memory.". The gouping is done in the java application not the database server. So _a lot_ more is transferred to the Application. Just use it with small Resultsets!